# Data listings in snowflake marketplace

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way to restrict snowflake roles to get/request only a selected list of datasets from the snowflake marketplace. For example, I want to allow only approved datasets to be get/request from snowflake market place

Comment: yes, dont make them admin. they can just see marketplace but can not request/add anything.

Answer (score 1):

By default only ACCOUNTADMIN role can import the datasets. When a different role tries to import a data set it will throw an error:

> Your current role (ROLE_NAME) lacks privileges to get data products. Use a role with IMPORT SHARE and CREATE DATABASE privileges or contact your account admin to get this data product for you.

So, as per the error message users will have to reach out to the account admin to get the dataset for them.

[Documentation](https://other-docs.snowflake.com/en/collaboration/consumer-becoming.html#set-up-required-privileges)

Comment: Actually, I know that but what I wanted to check is if it is possible to restrict ADMIN also to be able to see only datasets approved by an organization. I think probably private data exchange can do that, but not really sure if that also has a feature to restrict to only approved datasets by role

Comment: @RajibDeb There are two things to consider. 1. Publicly listed datasets on the Marketplace are visible for everyone, once it is visible it can be imported by the role with required privileges. 2. ACCOUNTADMIN is the highest possible level of permissions, in this case the accountadmin users act on behalf of the organization, so they should control what they import.

Comment: Thanks, but a process needs to be in place to be able to govern this activity. I have an idea to marry a data catalog and marketplace to bring some governance. I will try that out